# Inserting records two time in table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

```
$Notification = 1;
      $userTo = $_GET['id'];
      $message_subject = $_POST['MessageSubject'];
      $message_text = $_POST['MessageText'];
      $query = "insert into message (MUserId) values ('$Userid')";
      $run = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
      if($run)
      {
        echo "<script>alert('successfull')</script>";
        exit; 

      }
```

I have this simple .php file to insert data into mySQL database, but instead of once it does it two times with one request.
How can I stop this?

Comment: Impossible, not with that small fragment of code would you get duplicate inserts.

Comment: try it with that 
      if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$query))

Comment: I would also recommend using PDO in a try catch block on top of what mooga said. 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: More codes please

Comment: It maybe possible that this piece of code is called twice due to some reason. Because this code alone cannot possibly be inserting records twice. Please recheck